# FileNotFoundException after migrating from .Net framework to NET

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, migration

During the migration of our software from .Net framework 4.8 to NET 6, I encountered the following error at runtime when running the project called "Viewer":

```
Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Common.Utilities.ApplicationProperties' threw an exception.'

Inner exception:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CodeBase.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a395f90ece4b52e0'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The core dll is present in the build folders, it seems to have the right version (matching File properties in the explorer), the public token seems to be the right one (matching the output of ([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("pathToCore")).FullName).

I tried to use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer to verify where the "CodeBase.Viewer" project is looking for the "CodeBase.Core" dll but I could not locate the exception mentioned above in this tool.

I tried to remove the project reference and add it again wihtout success.

I tried to change "copy to local folder" to true in the project properties references without success.

This issue is particularly puzzling because another project of the same Visual Studio solution (CodeBase.csproj) is able to call the same line of code at runtime without any issue.

Working project file (CodeBase.csproj):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Import Project="..\CodeBase.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeBase\</OutputPath>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\CodeBase.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>$(BuiltPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeAnalysis\$(MSBuildProjectName).CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>false</EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <DocumentationFile>$(BuiltPath)CodeBase\x64\Release\CodeBase\CodeBase.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>..\CodeBase.Common\Resources\Icons\CodeBase.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\CodeBase.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\CodeBase.ruleset">
      <Link>CodeBase.ruleset</Link>
    </None>
    <None Include="..\CodeBase.snk">
      <Link>CodeBase.snk</Link>
    </None>
    <AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Activation\CodeBase.Activation.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Common\CodeBase.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Controls\CodeBase.Controls.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Converter\CodeBase.Converter.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Core\CodeBase.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Graphics\CodeBase.Graphics.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Home\CodeBase.Home.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO.Data\CodeBase.IO.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO.Options\CodeBase.IO.Options.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO\CodeBase.IO.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Library\CodeBase.Library.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.License\CodeBase.License.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Public\CodeBase.Public.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.SDK\CodeBase.SDK.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.UI.Graphics\CodeBase.UI.Graphics.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.UI.Options\CodeBase.UI.Options.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Viewer\CodeBase.Viewer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.WindowsShellExtensions\CodeBase.WindowsShellExtensions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Workspace\CodeBase.Workspace.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Images\Logo.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Images\SplashScreen.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>echo *** Post-build $(MSBuildProjectName) ***
powershell.exe "&amp; '$(SolutionDir)..\Powershell\Deploy.ps1'" $(Platform)\$(Configuration)
echo *** End of post-build $(MSBuildProjectName) ***</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Broken project (CodeBase.Viewer.csproj):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Import Project="..\CodeBase.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeBase\</OutputPath>   
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\CodeBase.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>$(BuiltPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeAnalysis\$(MSBuildProjectName).CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>false</EnableDefaultApplicationDefinition>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <DocumentationFile>$(BuiltPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeBase\CodeBase.Viewer.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>..\CodeBase.Common\Resources\Icons\CodeBase.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\CodeBase.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\CodeBase.ruleset">
      <Link>CodeBase.ruleset</Link>
    </None>
    <None Include="..\CodeBase.snk">
      <Link>CodeBase.snk</Link>
    </None>
    <AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Scripting\Python.Classic.xshd" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Scripting\Python.ModernDark.xshd" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Scripting\Python.ModernLight.xshd" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Scripting\Python.Visualize.xshd" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Common\CodeBase.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Controls\CodeBase.Controls.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Core\CodeBase.Core.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Drawing\CodeBase.Drawing.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Geometry\CodeBase.Geometry.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Graphics\CodeBase.Graphics.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO.Data\CodeBase.IO.Data.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO.Options\CodeBase.IO.Options.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO\CodeBase.IO.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.License\CodeBase.License.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.LinearAlgebra\CodeBase.LinearAlgebra.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Scripting\CodeBase.Scripting.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.UI.Graphics\CodeBase.UI.Graphics.csproj">       
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ViewModels\Markups\SelectionBoxViewModel.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: please post the csproj contents of the "err'ing" csproj AND the "working" csproj.

Comment: Csproj files have been added.